# Why is postgres faster than LMDB?

Tags: postgresql, openldap, lmdb

I compared Postgres and LMDB by inserting 1 Million entries into each which have a mix of unique ID's and some array type values. In Postgres i used jsonb to store the array and in LMDB as attributes and multivalued attributes.

I ran this test on a Debian VM with 6GB RAM.

Postgres was a LOT faster than LMDB. Even when i did a search on the array type values by checking if a value existed in the array. Where the json column was not indexed and i was looking if a value existed in an json array.

Based on what i have read both of them used B-Tree's.

So shouldn't LMDB which is Memory mapped, be faster than Postgres, At least in some cases.

Here are the scripts i used to insert data into Postgres and MDB.

Postgres:

```
import psycopg2
import random
import string
import json
import time

connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname='name' user='user' host='localhost' password='test'")

cursor = connection.cursor()

count = 698595

ports = [80, 143, 3389, 22, 21, 8080, 443, 289, 636]

def get_random_ports():
    l_ports = list(ports)
    num_service = random.randrange(len(ports))
    result = []
    for i in range(num_port):
        l_i = random.randrange(len(l_ports))
        result.append(l_ports[l_i])
        l_services.pop(l_i)
    return result

def get_random_string():
    stringLength = random.randrange(5, 15)
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(stringLength))

def show_progress(n):

    print "|" + ("".join("." for _ in range(n))) + ("".join(" " for _ in range(99 - n))) + "|", "\r" if n < 100 else "\n",


start_time = time.time()
postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO test (port, name) VALUES (%s::jsonb, %s)"""
current_count = 0.0
while current_count < count:

    record_to_insert = (
        json.dumps({"services": get_random_services()}),
        get_random_name()
    )

    try:
        cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
        connection.commit()
        current_count = current_count + 1
        show_progress(int((current_count / count) * 100))
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
        connection.rollback()

connection.close()

print(str(time.time() - start_time))
```

MDB:

```
import uuid
import random
import string
import json
import time
import ldap
from ldap import modlist

connection = ldap.initialize('ldapi:///')
connection.simple_bind_s('cn=admin,dc=local', 'doc')

count = 1

ports = [80, 143, 3389, 22, 21, 8080, 443, 289, 636]

def get_random_ports():
    l_ports = list(ports)
    num_service = random.randrange(len(ports))
    result = []
    for i in range(num_port):
        l_i = random.randrange(len(l_ports))
        result.append(l_ports[l_i])
        l_services.pop(l_i)
    return result

def get_random_name():
    stringLength = random.randrange(5, 15)
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for _ in range(stringLength))

start_time = time.time()
session_id = bytes(str(uuid.uuid4()), 'utf-8')
while count > 0:

    try:

        name = bytes(get_random_hostname(), 'utf-8')

        entry = ldap.modlist.addModlist(
            {
                "name": name,
                "port": get_random_services(),
                "objectClass": bytes('tmp', 'utf-8')
            }
        )

        connection.add_s('name=' + name + ",dc=local", entry)

        count = count - 1

    except Exception as err:
        pass

print(str(time.time() - start_time))
```

After inserting 1M entries each. i tried a basic search on name and ports. Didn't need to run multiple searches as openldap didn't return in 1s. If there's some other information needed. please let me know.

Comment: An LDAP server is no database.

Comment: Yeah, i am talking about LMDB here. which is one of the DB backends for openldap.

Comment: The Postgres team has been focused on delivering incredible performance gains in order to remain competitive with MongoDB, MySQL and others. Can you say the same about the team working on LMDB? What are their priorities? Postgres is honestly ridiculously performant. The change in performance characteristics from Postgres 9 to 11 is astonishing.

Comment: Apples and oranges. The goals of an LDAP database are completely different from the goals of a normal relational database. Specifically, the transactional requirements are relaxed and reads are prioritized over writes to a very considerable degree.

Comment: exactly, as the dB is optimised for reads I expected it be faster, and this is not some assumption I made on my own. I have read ldap vs rdms related docs and found that they keep saying lmdb gets a higher read performance. I get that ldap is used for different purposes. Anyway I guess postgres is faster and that's that.

Comment: you could be using bad configurations on lmdb. lmdb is very unopinionated about a lot of things, specially when it comes to lmdb api calls. and it is not very straightforward to use. these apis are open to abuse and it manifests in the overall app performance. [ref](https://github.com/sidnt/lmdz/issues/)

Comment: So, what would you suggest. Am using openldap now, is there something else that can give better results.

Comment: Your OpenLDAP server configuration would be relevant here. Most likely, you haven't configured any indices on the attributes you're searching on.

On a properly configured server, OpenLDAP reads are orders of magnitude faster than all SQL servers.

You should also provide the scripts you used to measure the search performance. You should also beware, Python is a lot slower than C; your measured performance will be much slower than OpenLDAP can actually deliver.

Comment: I have used python only for insertion. for read I basically did it manually. I just ran a query in psql with \timing on and for openldap I just used ldap search and timed the command with time command in bash. I didn't add any indices though so will check that tmr and see if there's a difference.

Answer (score 3):

In testing I did several years ago, on a properly tuned/configured OpenLDAP instance, with a 5 million entry database, the performance for back-mdb was approximately 61,000 reads/second.  And it's certainly possible to get much higher performance than that, I was trying to go for something that was particularly exhaustive.

https://mishikal.wordpress.com/2013/05/16/openldap-a-comparison-of-back-mdb-and-back-hdb-performance/

Comment: will check the link. i agree I don't know much, this was an effort to learn more abt it. I didn't jump to any conclusion, wanted to know what I can do to get full performance out lmdb so that I can better compare my use case. Also other than indices, can u suggest some leads on performance tuning of lmdb. the only documentation I can find is abt different ways I can design my data, but not abt performance.

Comment: @fiatjaf removed critical information from this response, this should not have been done.  How do I report them?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm answering a very old question here, but I'm answering for people who might come across this in the future.

So, the root of the issue here, is that while you might be using LMDB as the backing store for your OpenLDAP instance, that doesn't mean that you're getting the same performance as if you were using LMDB directly.
OpenLDAP isn't designed to store arbitrary data, it's designed to store the organisational directory and authentication information.

To do a direct comparison you'd need to use something like this library https://lmdb.readthedocs.io/en/release/

Also, the code you've posted doesn't work (you're calling `get_random_services()` which doesn't exist, but I think you meant to call `get_random_ports()` which is defined in your code), and wouldn't be an accurate way to evaluate either case, as you're blindly silencing exceptions that could be telling you about timeouts, or connection issues.